# Populating multiple arrays with output from a loop

Tags: arrays, bash

How to store results of loops in arrays?

Given the following bash script:

```
types=("active_power" "_voltage" "_current" "total_active_energy")

function retrieveSensors () {
  curl \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    "$endpoint/states" \
    | jq '.[] | select(.entity_id | startswith("sensor.shelly"))' \
    | grep entity_id \
    | sed 's/"entity_id": "\(.*\)",/\1/'
}

for str in ${types[@]}; do
  retrieveSensors | grep $str
done
```

I'm struggling to get the output (4x lists of sensor entities) stored in 4x arrays. I have tried:

```
declare -a output

for str in "${types[@]}"; do
  output+=$(retrieveSensors | grep $str)
done

var1="${output[0]}"
var2="${output[1]}"
var3="${output[2]}"
var4="${output[3]}"
```

...to no avail. var1..var4 are empty.
I assume there's a hella easy trick I'm missing here. Asssistance would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

to be clear, when using only

```
for str in ${types[@]}; do
  retrieveSensors | grep $str
done
```

The script correctly prints to screen the 4x expected lists of specified sensor types, voltage sensors, current, etc.

The JSON output from `$endpoint/states` for a given sensor is:

```
  {
    "entity_id": "sensor.shellypro3em_c8f09e8968b0_phase_c_total_active_energy",
    "state": "50.53842",
    "attributes": {
      "state_class": "total_increasing",
      "unit_of_measurement": "kWh",
      "device_class": "energy",
      "friendly_name": "shellypro3em-c8f09e8968b0 phase c total active energy"
    },
    "last_changed": "2023-05-25T15:36:59.985247+00:00",
    "last_updated": "2023-05-25T15:36:59.985247+00:00",
    "context": {
      "id": "01H19RWRAHXP5P2ZCG85W8Y131",
      "parent_id": null,
      "user_id": null
    }
  },
```

There are hundreds of sensors, which I need to filter.

From this crazy long JSON list, I need the `entity_id`s matching:

```
startswith("sensor.shelly")
```

AND

```
types=("active_power" "_voltage" "_current" "total_active_energy")
```

It has now occured to me that I do not need to store the filtered list of appropriate `entity_id`s in multiple arrays - a single array would do just fine!

Comment: it's `output+=( stuff )` like `output+=("$(command)")`. Check your scripts with shellcheck.

Comment: I have now tried:

`output+=("$(retrieveSensors | grep "$str")")`

Array still appears empty to me using:
`echo ${var1[*]}`

Comment: since `str` is not referenced in the function, it appears the function is being called 4 times to generate the same set of output 4 times (ie, it appears it would be more efficient to perform a single function call); please update the question with the complete output from a single function call; also, please update the question with the expected result (corresponding to the sample inputs)

Comment: Adding
`for str in "${var1[@]}"; do
  echo $str
done'

to the script shows that var1 does, indeed contain items. So perhaps I simply don't know how to tell whether an array is populated or not. 

Comment: is the intention to have `N` arrays with names `var1`, `var2`, ...., `varN`,  where `N` is the number of elements in the `types[]` array?

Comment: `echo` is not a good tool to use to check array contents. Use `declare -p output` instead. BTW, `grep $str` should __always__ be `grep "$str"`, `${types[@]}` should **always** be `"${types[@]}"`, etc.

Comment: BTW, any reason you're piping from jq to grep instead of having jq itself do the filtering you need? In particular, if you use `jq -c` you can force its output to be line-oriented.

Comment: I would actually be happy to have all outputs appended to a single array. I'm not certain why I feel I needed multiple arrays.
Objective is to have an array of all sensors I will use to iterate through later.

Comment: Part of why I'm just commenting here and not writing an answer, btw, is that I don't know what your code's _expected_ behavior is. It'd be helpful to build a [mre] we can run ourselves on our own machines to test proposed answers without needing access to a web service only you have. Think about a function that instead of calling `curl` writes a constant heredoc to stdout (`cat <<EOF` etc), then code to process the output of that heredoc, with well-defined expected-vs-actual results that can be constructed in light of the specific heredoc you include in the question.

Comment: (Personally, I'd probably make jq write four lines, one for each type of data you want to extract... but can't test any answer along those lines without knowing the format of the JSON content)

Comment: `var1="${output[0]}"` assigns a *string* to the scalar variable `var1`; `var1` is *not* an array; run `typeset -p var1` to see what's stored in the variable; having said that ... an oddity of `bash` is that it will ignore [*]` and `[@]` when appended to a scalar variable reference (ie, it treats `var1[@]` as a reference to `var1`)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I wouldn't know how to filter by ("active_power" "_voltage" "_current" "total_active_energy") using jq, though this really seems the logical thing to do... cannot wrap my head around this.

Comment: Depends on the context of your JSON. Are those substrings in a textual element? Keys in a dict? Again, if I actually saw the JSON format I could just write an example.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. As others have said, it's not clear what *exactly* you're trying to achieve (especially since your code only contains one array and you haven't shown what the data looks like), so please make a [mre]. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: one array or multiple arrays ... same requirement applies ... provide the sample input (ie, complete output from function call) and the expected result (ie, contents of the array(s))

Comment: I'll pile on here. I find the `min reprod examp` too high level and abstract to take in for new or inexperienced users. Read the section "How to turn a bad script into a good question" in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info to get a step-by-step, down-to-earth example of implementing `min reprod examp` in shell (and other languages). ... I agree with the comments above. Good luck!

Comment: (I think this has gotten a great deal better since it was first asked -- smells answerable now, at least if we assume the top-level structure of the JSON document is just a list)

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, though I'm filling in some gaps and the result doesn't seem to be what you want, but at least not all the variables are empty. Make sure we can copy-paste a chunk of code, run it, and get the same output. To start, that means providing valid JSON (trailing comma is invalid and it seems to be missing the outer square brackets that would put it in an array).

Comment: BTW, the "cannot index array with string" is just because you tried to use `jq -r '.entity_id'` instead of `jq -r '.[] | .entity_id'` -- one needs to traverse the array to get to the maps in which entity_id exists as an element.

Comment: Please use the "Add an Answer" button to add your own answer _as an answer_. Answers aren't allowed in questions -- see [Answer the question... inside the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387723/answer-a-question-inside-the-question), and [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que).

Comment: (And when editing questions, we don't require or request use of "edit markers" here -- an ideal edit makes the question more accessible to people who are seeing it _for the first time_, and doesn't invalidate preexisting answers; people who wrote those preexisting answers can just view history if they want to see what changed, and because question edits aren't allowed to invalidate answers, there's no concern about them making an answer no longer make sense).

Answer (score 3):

First, let's break this down into smaller pieces. For example, in your *real* code you might have:

```
retrieveSensors() {
  curl \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    "$endpoint/states"
}
```

but in this example, I'm instead going to use:

```
retrieveSensors() {
  cat <<'EOF'
[
  {
    "entity_id": "sensor.shellypro3em_c8f09e8968b0_phase_c_total_active_energy",
    "state": "50.53842",
    "attributes": {
      "state_class": "total_increasing",
      "unit_of_measurement": "kWh",
      "device_class": "energy",
      "friendly_name": "shellypro3em-c8f09e8968b0 phase c total active energy"
    },
    "last_changed": "2023-05-25T15:36:59.985247+00:00",
    "last_updated": "2023-05-25T15:36:59.985247+00:00",
    "context": {
      "id": "01H19RWRAHXP5P2ZCG85W8Y131",
      "parent_id": null,
      "user_id": null
    }
  }
]
EOF
}
```

---

Given one of the above, we can run:

```
readarray -t matchingSensorIds < <(
  retrieveSensors | jq -r '
    .[]
    | .entity_id
    | select(
        test(
          "sensor.shelly.*(active_power|_voltage|_current|total_active_energy)"
        )
      )
  '
)
```

...or, for compatibility with ancient pre-4.0 bash releases:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a matchingSensorIds < <(
  retrieveSensors | jq -r '
    .[]
    | .entity_id
    | select(
        test(
          "sensor.shelly.*(active_power|_voltage|_current|total_active_energy)"
        )
      )
  ' && printf '\0'
)
```

...which will create an array like the following:

```
$ declare -p matchingSensorIds
declare -a matchingSensorIds=([0]="sensor.shellypro3em_c8f09e8968b0_phase_c_total_active_energy")
```

containing only those sensor ids that start with `sensor.shelly` and contain `active_power`, `_voltage`, `_current`, or `total_active_energy`.

Comment: Thanks, Charles
I read about the readarray function earlier today... macOS is running bash 3.2, it seems, which knows nothing of the readarray function.  : (

Comment: In that case you can use `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a matchingSensorIds < <(jq ... && printf '\0')`, though I'd really recommend installing a modern version of bash (my personally preferred package manager is [Nix](https://nixos.org/), but it's something you could also do with Macports, Homebrew, etc).

Comment: the common `array=( $(command) )` idiom is buggy, for the reasons described in [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_.2BICY.29_.29), to explain why I'm advising something that's more verbose.